Request y limits en kubernetes
estoy iniciando en Kubernetes y tengo dudas sobre cómo asignar correctamente los valores de requests y limits para un deployment.
¿Cuáles son los pasos que suelen seguir para definir estos valores? ¿Primero montan la imagen en Docker para observar el uso base de CPU y memoria y luego le agregan algún porcentaje extra? ¿Realizan pruebas de estrés para determinar estos valores?
Cualquier orientación o buenas prácticas serían de gran ayuda. ¡Gracias!

Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.
